# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ISet<string>'

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, type-conversion, kentico

I am getting Error **'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ISet''**

for this code snippet

```
foreach (GridViewRow grv in customTableDataList.UniGrid.GridView.Rows)
{
  if (grv != null)
  {
    if (null != grv.FindControl(ItemCheckBoxID) && ((CheckBox)grv.FindControl(ItemCheckBoxID)).Checked)
    {
      //At this line I am getting error.
      itemIds += customTableDataList.UniGrid.ActionsID[rowCounter] + ", ";  
    }
    rowCounter++;
  }
}
```

Can anyone give some more details to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new using:

```
System.Linq;
```

and change

```
foreach (GridViewRow grv in customTableDataList.UniGrid.GridView.Rows)
{
  if (grv != null)
  {
    if (null != grv.FindControl(ItemCheckBoxID) && ((CheckBox)grv.FindControl(ItemCheckBoxID)).Checked)
    {
      itemIds += customTableDataList.UniGrid.ActionsID.ToArray()[rowCounter] + ", ";
    }
    rowCounter++;
  }
}
```